# Adding session affinity via BackendConfig results in service outage (502)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

After adding session affinity via IPs to my service it resulted in 503s of my page I not yet understand why that happened.

The service itself did not throw any errors, but on the load balancer (LB) logs I see that the LB could not connect to the service anymore.

I am quite sure the outage was a result of adding the backend config, because the moment I removed the annotation the page recovered.

It would be really great if you could help me to find out why that happened and how I prevent that going forward, as I still want enable the session affinity.

---

Service annotations:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "SimonsBackendConf"}'
...
```

Backend config:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: SimonsBackendConf
spec:
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "CLIENT_IP"
```

Log entry which leads me to thinking it might be the service not being available:

```
{
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
    "statusDetails": "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 502,
...
  },
...
}
```

---

Setup:

- gke
- L7 google managed load balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for session affinity to work, you need to be running a VPC-native cluster as session affinity requires network endpoint groups.  You will also need to create an Ingress resource for your service as well.

Assuming you have a VPC-native cluster, you'll need to add an additional annotation to your service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "SimonsBackendConf"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
...
```

Note that the backend-config annotation is now GA as well (not sure which GKE version you are on)

Comment: We are on a VPC native cluster :D Yeah I already updated the backend-config to GA (v1), but that also does not explain the outage with the beta.

Comment: Did you have the `cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'`  annotation on your service as well?

Comment: Using the GA version of the backend config and the annotations fixed it for me. Zero downtime on apply. Thanks!

The `cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'` annotation was not required

Answer (score 0):

when a container doesn't explicitly handle `SIGTERM`, it immediately terminates and stops handling requests. The load balancer continues to send incoming traffic to the terminated container, leading to 502 error.

The resolution for this issue would be to configure containers to handle `SIGTERM` [2] and continue responding to requests throughout the termination grace period (30 seconds by default). Configure Pods to begin failing health checks when they receive `SIGTERM`.This signal lets the containers know that they are going to be shut down soon. This will also signal the load balancer to stop sending traffic to the Pod while endpoint deprograming is in progress.

Your code should listen for this event and start shutting down cleanly at this point. This may include stopping any long-lived connections (WebSocket stream), saving the current state, or anything like that.

If your application does not gracefully shut down and stops responding to requests when receiving a `SIGTERM`, the preStop hook[3] can be used to handle SIGTERM and keep serving traffic while endpoint deprograming is in progress.

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      # if SIGTERM triggers a quick exit; keep serving traffic instead
      command: ["sleep","60"]
```

Kindly refer the below link to find more detailed information related to this in the document [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing#traffic_does_not_reach_endpoints

[2] SIGTERM: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

[3] preStop hook: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-details

Comment: Nice one as well :) WIll add that SIGTERM handling to my service